# В mediaelement.js как менять title?

Tags: javascript, html, css

В mediaelement.js как менять title (Play/Pause, Mute Toggle, Fullscreen) ?

```html
<div class="reviewsVideo">                      
    <video width="400" height="292" style="width:100%; height:100%;" poster="media/poster__reviews.png">
        <source src="media/video__reviews.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>  
</div>
```

Comment: Да. Надо менять или выключить.

Comment: Можно через [файлы локализации](https://github.com/mediaelement/mediaelement/blob/master/src/js/languages/ru.js), если я вас правильно понял

Comment: Ссылка не работает (404).

Comment: Попробуйте так https://github.com/mediaelement/mediaelement/blob/master/src/js/languages/ru.js